# XAML - Access an array value from a template, indexed by the containing column position

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I have an desktop WPF application that shows values from different files, the objective being to compare those files. The values extracted from the files are displayed in a `DataGrid`, one column per file. The user can add or remove files at will, which means that the amount of columns displayed in the grid can change. Columns are created and removed from a ViewModel, and have complex content that requires the use of `DataGridTemplateColumn` instances.

The data source is basically a two dimentionnal array (something like `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<CellViewModel>>`).

To fill my cells I need a data template, but the problem is that the DataTemplate's data source will be the row. And if I want to display the correct value, I'll have to know the index of the current cell from the template, so I access the correct index in my row. In the end, I'd like to be able to have a binding in the template that looks like `{Binding Path=[someIndex].DisplayText}` (DisplayText being a property of my CellViewModel).

I hope I've been clear enough :)

So the question is : how do I read the correct index in my row from the template ? Or, is there some better way to handle this variable-sized templated columns list problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that your rows are constant, right? Can you pivot your data so that columns will be constant and rows will represent each file?

Comment: My rows are constant yes. Unfortunately having one file per line is not an acceptable change for this application